# Fatal error: Call to undefined function FusionCharts()

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I want to use Fusion Charts for my project and I have used to code in the following link: http://www.fusioncharts.com/php-charts/
The problem is that the chart does not display when I run the code. The browser keeps displaying this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function FusionCharts() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Audit_Project\pie_chart.php on line 15
```

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
<?php

    include("PDF/fusioncharts.php");
    // Create the chart - Column 2D Chart with data given in constructor parameter 
    // Syntax for the constructor - 

         new FusionCharts("type of chart", 
            "unique chart id", 
            "width of chart", 
            "height of chart", 
            "div id to render the chart", 
            "type of data", 
            "actual data");

            $Chart = new FusionCharts("column2d", "ex1" , 600, 400, "chart-1", "json", '{  
           "chart":{  
              "caption":"Harry\'s SuperMart",
              "subCaption":"Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
              "numberPrefix":"$",
              "theme":"ocean"
           },
           "data":[  
              {  
                 "label":"Bakersfield Central",
                 "value":"880000"
              },
              {  
                 "label":"Garden Groove harbour",
                 "value":"730000"
              },
              {  
                 "label":"Los Angeles Topanga",
                 "value":"590000"
              },
              {  
                 "label":"Compton-Rancho Dom",
                 "value":"520000"
              },
              {  
                 "label":"Daly City Serramonte",
                 "value":"330000"
              }
           ]
        }');
    // Render the chart
    $Chart->render();
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Home</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts.theme.ocean.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see on GitHub, it has only one class called FusionCharts, wich is not a function. $chart = new FusionCharts();

Comment: I missed the 'new' in the code. Now no error is displayed. But also, no chart is displaying. It's blank.

Comment: Did you pass everything to its __construct, and invoke the render method? $chart->render();

Comment: Yes. I have a php page called (pie_chart.php) where I have included the fusioncharts.php and the js libraries mentioned.

Comment: Did you supply with valid data? Could you show your full code?

Comment: Are you sure the path of the js files are correct? They should be at the same folder as the php script, that way it works for me. You can get them from here. http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/free/

Comment: how many js files should I link in the page? Only two of them?

Comment: can I see your code where you've linked the js script?

Comment: Sure, and I forgot to mention that you need an empty div where the JS will generate the chart. I put the downloaded js files in a js folder. Code: http://pastebin.com/N8qPcUxy

Comment: Thanks. But now, it says: Chart type is not supported

Comment: Try with this, I have no more ideas. :D https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0iioidzrb2r9eq/chart.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: still not working. I'll try to use other charts. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to comment out below part of your code:

```
new FusionCharts("type of chart", 
            "unique chart id", 
            "width of chart", 
            "height of chart", 
            "div id to render the chart", 
            "type of data", 
            "actual data");
```

Or you can refer to this page for the right working code: http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/php/introduction.html